# Unable to install bundle for Symfony 3 using Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, symfony

I am trying to install the oauth server bundle using Composer:

http://knpbundles.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle

However I get the following confusing error messages. Any ideas?

Is this because this bundle has not been adapted to the new Symfony3? Is there an alternate bundle which has similar capabilities i.e. API key authentication?

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.1
    - Installation request for friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle >=1.4.2 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle[1.4.2].
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle 1.4.2 requires symfony/security-bundle ~2.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/security-bundle[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.8.0, v2.8.1].
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.14|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.15|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.16|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.17|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.18|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.19|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.20|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.21|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.22|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.23|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.24|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.25|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.26|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.27|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.28|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.29|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.30|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.31|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.32|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.33|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.34|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.35|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.36|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.4.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.4.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.4.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.4.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.4.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.4.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.4.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.4.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.4.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.4.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.4.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.5.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.5.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.5.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.5.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.5.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.5.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.5.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.5.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.5.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.5.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.5.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.5.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.5.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.2.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.2.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.2.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.2.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.2.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.2.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.2.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.2.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.2.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.2.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.2.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony 3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.0.0, v3.0.1].
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, if you look into the master documentation of the project:
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/README.md
Its compatible only with 2>

This bundle is also super outdated as you can see here:
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/commits/master

Including the other branches!

So what would I recommend?
Go for league OAuth 2 Server, its not plug and play as the bundles, its a standalone library, but maybe you are able to find a bundle for it!

Link to the lib: http://oauth2.thephpleague.com/

I hope this helps you!